# generate permutation of numbers for any k,m

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, permutation

I have a task to generate permutation of numbers stored in *k* arrays. For *k* = 3 and *m* = 3 the first tuple would be (arr<sub>0</sub>[0], arr<sub>1</sub>[0], arr<sub>2</sub>[0]) and the last tuple (arr<sub>0</sub>[2], arr<sub>1</sub>[2], arr<sub>2</sub>[2]). It has to work for any *k* and *m*, where *k* would be typically between 1 and 4. Example output for *k* = 3, *m* = 3:

```
(0,0 1,0 2,0) 
(0,0 1,0 2,1) 
(0,0 1,0 2,2)
(0,0 1,1 2,0)
(0,0 1,1 2,1)
(0,0 1,1 2,2)
(0,0 1,2 2,0)
(0,0 1,2 2,1)
(0,0 1,2 2,2)

(0,1 1,0 2,0) 
(0,1 1,0 2,1) 
(0,1 1,0 2,2)
(0,1 1,1 2,0)
(0,1 1,1 2,1)
(0,1 1,1 2,2)
(0,1 1,2 2,0)
(0,1 1,2 2,1)
(0,1 1,2 2,2)

(0,2 1,0 2,0) 
(0,2 1,0 2,1) 
(0,2 1,0 2,2)
(0,2 1,1 2,0)
(0,2 1,1 2,1)
(0,2 1,1 2,2)
(0,2 1,2 2,0)
(0,2 1,2 2,1)
(0,2 1,2 2,2)
```

some java code to start with. The run method has 3 nested loops because *k* = 3

```
package perm;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Loop {

    private final int m;
    private final int k;

    public Loop(int m, int k) {
        this.m = m;
        this.k = k;
    }

    public void tuple(int l, int j, int i) {
        //todo tuple must have dynamic size k
        int[] t = new int[3];
        t[0] = l;
        t[1] = j;
        t[2] = i;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t));
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < m; l++) {
                    tuple(l, j, i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Loop(3, 4).run();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: Please show what you've done so far.

Comment: At what university they told you to do that?

Comment: @xenteros you wouldn't believe me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple recursive algorithm to do this.

```
private static void permute(int[][] arrays)
{
    permute(arrays, 0, new int[arrays.length]);
}

private static void permute(int[][] arrays, int arrayBeingModified, int[] tmp)
{
    if(arrayBeingModified >= arrays.length)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tmp));
    }
    else
    {
        for(int v : arrays[arrayBeingModified])
        {
            tmp[arrayBeingModified] = v;
            permute(arrays, arrayBeingModified + 1, tmp);
            tmp[arrayBeingModified] = 0;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] arr0 = {2,4,8};
    int[] arr1 = {3,6,9,12};
    int[] arr2 = {5,10,15};
    permute(new int[][]{arr0, arr1, arr2});
}
```

The key concept here is the following:

- if you had 1 array you would use a single loop
- if you had only 2 arrays you would use a double nested loop
- etc

Whenever you feel yourself getting in a similar situation, think recursion.
Recursion is a way of replacing arbitrarily nested for loops.

In this particular example, the recursive code will keep track of temporary array (called tmp) that gets filled up with numbers from each of the corresponding arrays.

In a first step, we set the first element of tmp to every element of arrays[0] in turn. And once it has been set, call permute recursively to set the second element.

Comment: Thanks! I think I will be able to use your solution. In theory each recursion could be translated to iterative solution. I wonder, if this is possible in this case

Comment: Of course it's possible.For instance, in the simple case of m=3 and k=3, you know there will be a total of m^k (m to the power of k) outputs.
Suppose you want the output at position N. This can be computed as arr0[N/9], arr1[(N/9)%3], arr2[N%3].
Similarly, a generic formula can be found to handle arbitrary m and k.